# How to fix android.os.DeadObjectException android X

Tags: android

When android unbind a service I created (service.MyService), I see the
following DeadObjectException.

Can you please tell me how  what does this mean and can I fix this exception?

```
W/ActivityManager(  583): Exception when unbinding service
com.mycompany/.service.MyService
W/ActivityManager(  583): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager(  583):       at
android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  583):       at
android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.scheduleUnbindService(ApplicationThreadNative.java:516)
W/ActivityManager(  583):       at
com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.removeConnectionLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:9609)
W/ActivityManager(  583):       at
com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.killServicesLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8515)
...
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This means that your service had already stopped - either killed from the OS, or stopped from your application.

Does this problem happen every time you debug your project?

Override your service's `onDestroy()` method and watch what event flow leads to it. If you catch `DeadObjectException` without going through this method, your service should have been killed by the OS.

Comment: Does android Service have any onStop() ? I think it is having onDestroy()

Comment: @ShailAdi you are right , there is no opStop for android service

Comment: The solution then is to kill the service in the hosting activity as that activity gets destroyed?

Comment: its not working . Please provide effective suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar logs, and I simply did scroll few hundred log-lines up, and the actual error was there!

I mean, the `DeadObjectException` is in most cases just a follow-up error, and not the root cause, keep searching the logs upwards ;-)