# java.lang.RuntimeException: system server dead?

Tags: android, android-widget, forceclose

My appwidget crashes with following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.android.mlweatherwidget.WeatherWidgetLarge: java.lang.RuntimeException: system server dead?
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1805)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: system server dead?
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at com.android.mlhome.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(AppWidgetManager.java:375)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at com.android.mlweatherwidget.WeatherWidgetLarge.onReceive(WeatherWidgetLarge.java:202)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572): Caused by: android.os.DeadObjectException
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at com.android.mlhome.appwidget.ILauncherAppWidget$Stub$Proxy.getAppWidgetIds(ILauncherAppWidget.java:256)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    at com.android.mlhome.appwidget.AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(AppWidgetManager.java:369)
E/AndroidRuntime( 5572):    ... 12 more
```

Can anybody understand from the above log what exactly is causing this error?

Comment: unable to start receiver you system server was dead

Comment: my intention is to know why the system server dies? in what circumstances?

Answer (score 0):

[How to fix android.os.DeadObjectException android X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573557/how-to-fix-android-os-deadobjectexception-android-x)
this guy met the same issue, check this link out.

I copyed the answer  written by Dimitar Dimitrov as follows

> This means that your service had already stopped - either killed from
>   the OS, or stopped from your application.
>
> Does this problem happen every time you debug your project?
>
> Override your service's onDestroy() method and watch what event flow
>   leads to it. If you catch DeadObjectException without going through
>   this method, your service should have been killed by the OS.