# Android dead object exception from TextToSpeech

Tags: android, exception, text-to-speech

Please does anybody know what could cause this exception?
http://cl.ly/370E3C4425162j2F2b3h (screenshot from LogCat)

That is how I am calling the TextToSpeech

```
public void say(String text, Context context, String utteranceID){
    if(mTts == null){
        this.text = text;

        mTts = new TextToSpeech(context, (OnInitListener) helper);

    }
    else{
        map.clear();
        map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utteranceID);
        mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map);
    }
}
```

The TextToSpeech actually works as it should (but as you can see not at all:), but since my app uses TTS really often I am holding TTS instance in custom helper class..and some time I got the exception. It comes incidentally, sometimes it just works, sometimes the UI freezes for sometime and then is thrown the exception. (whole thing is part of blind-enabled UI)

[How to fix android.os.DeadObjectException android X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573557/how-to-fix-android-os-deadobjectexception-android-x)

actually this is possible solution..but after looking at the stack trace I think my problem is different

Comment: You should check your context value and where and when you are calling say(). Maybe the context is destroyed and hence DeadObjectException.