# android.os.deadobjectexception in service android

Tags: java, android, service

I have an application which takes data values (coordinates) from a service, and works fine, but crashes after about seven or eight minutes.

In logcat there appears a lot of this message:

> 02-24 09:50:35.761: E/RemoteException(6395): android.os.DeadObjectException

these messages are from the application not service, but I suppose that is because the service fails?

[**UPDATE**]

With the comments I understand better that the problems is caused by service's failure, but I read this question [How to fix android.os.DeadObjectException android X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573557/how-to-fix-android-os-deadobjectexception-android-x/1574355#1574355) (similar to mine) but the answer... is some confuse to me.

this is my `ondestroy():`

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {

 Toast.makeText(this, "Servicio destruido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Log.d("SERVICEBOOT", "Servicio destruido");
 capture.control(0);

}
```

How can I know which element closed my service?

Comment: **The object you are calling has died, because its hosting process no longer exists.**

Comment: Visit this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1574355/3330969)

Comment: i will update de post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using the instance of an object that no longer exist in memory as parent process is stopped.

Comment: I think you service is stopped as the Activity it has been bound to is destroyed.

Comment: So the solution is to stop the service in the Activities `onDestroy`?

Comment: yes if you dont need it after activity is finished otherwise you can unbind service in on Destroy and keep service running but to access services instance remember to make the instance static.

Answer (score 4):

Add this in Service Class. This will stop the app from crashing. 'onTaskRemoved' triggers when app is removed from ram

```
@Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent){
        stopSelf();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

 @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
//Your Runnable
        mRunnable=null;
    }
```

Comment: Why is the Thread.sleep needed here? Thanks!