# Crash when setting a new screen

Tags: java, android, crash, libgdx

In my almost finished game I want to set a new screen on game over. I got my game over method:

```
    private void gameOver(Label score) {
    for (Body body : worldBodies) {
        world.destroyBody(body);
    }
    dispose();
    ((Game) Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameOver());
}
```

Whenever the method gets called the screen freezes for a second and the game crashes with this statement:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION 
09-02 22:04:34.036      391-425/com.joelbrun.jetskirider.android A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 425 (GLThread 29501)
```

Comment: What steps have you taken so far to try and diagnose the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try updating your code to match the following:

```
private void gameOver(Label score) {
    for (Body body : worldBodies) {
        world.destroyBody(body);
    }
    dispose();
    myGame.setScreen(new GameOver());
}
```

The first problem was that you were disposing/loading the `GameOver` screen *inside* of your loop instead of *after* it.

The second problem was with your call to `Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()`. Every time you call that it returns a new instance of your `Game`. Instead you need to hold on to a reference to your game and instead use that.

If you still get the same error, make sure you are calling `dispose()` appropriately. If resources are disposed of before they have been released then you can get some pretty nasty crashes.

Comment: its still crashing with: JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION

Comment: @JoelBrun What is the rest of the exception?

Comment: So it looks like a parent process has died out, which is why you are getting  a [`DeadObjectException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html). Does it work when you don't call `dispose()`? Possibly look into [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1574355/1654818).

Comment: It also crashes without the dispose

Comment: Then when does it crash? When a `Body` is destroyed or sometime during the call to `setScreen`?

Comment: Its during the setScreen

Comment: See this thread for more details: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12869

Comment: I dont really understand what I have to do... where do I have to put this code mentioned in the thread? @Jimmy

Comment: I have no clue what your application structure is, but I've typically done one of two things. The first is to store the `Game` instance in a static property on a static class, something like `GameVariables.Game`. Then you can reference that anywhere, but it's not very clean. The better option is wherever you instantiate your `Game` object pass that instance into each constructor for every single `Screen`/entity ([shown here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/ScreenAndGameClasses)).

Comment: I did what the link said but it still crashes

Comment: Hmm, sorry I couldn't help more, maybe someone else has had similar issues!

Comment: I just found it out! It was because I called gameOver() out of beginContact () which is an implemented class