# Binder runtime exception in android

Tags: android, deadobjectexception

i developed android app its in play store. I am getting binder error from lot of user i don't know how to solve. Can some one can help me on that. This is my log. I am useing google play service and also using `pro-guard`.

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.getAllSessions(PackageInstaller.java:406)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzl(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zzc.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpy.zzapv(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpy.zzc(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpv.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqa.zzc(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpp.onConnected(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnectionSuspended(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
Caused by android.os.DeadObjectException
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Binder.java)
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:511)
       at android.content.pm.IPackageInstaller$Stub$Proxy.getAllSessions(IPackageInstaller.java:360)
       at android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.getAllSessions(PackageInstaller.java:404)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zze.zzl(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.zzc.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpy.zzapv(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpy.zzc(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpv.begin(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqa.zzc(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzpp.onConnected(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk$1.onConnectionSuspended(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzd$zzd.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5740)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:766)
```

Comment: Same issue here. Not even using a Service, just Google Maps.

Did you find a solution by now?

Answer (score 2):

Based from this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadObjectException.html#DeadObjectException%28%29), you encountered an error because the object you are calling has died since its hosting process no longer exists. Also, as stated in this [thread](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/10759), it usually happens when the go side has crashed. Often the useful error log (if any) is before the `android.os.DeadObjectException`.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573557/how-to-fix-android-os-deadobjectexception-android-x) might help you:

> Override your service's `onDestroy()` method and watch what event flow leads to it. If you catch `DeadObjectException` without going through this method, your service should have been killed by the OS.

Comment: thanks, but i can't reproduce it is there any way to find which class is it happen.